# Rails 3 similar form on different page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I currently have these fields (`:name :email :password :password_confirmation :image :desktopinfo`) on one form. I would like to have `:image` and `:desktopinfo` on another page as well.

The current code for the first form is this:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>

    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>

    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

    <%= f.label :image %>
     <%= f.file_field :image %>

    <%= f.label :desktopinfo, "Desktop Info" %>
    <%= f.text_area :desktopinfo %>
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

When adding the following code to the separate page, it goes to the edit page (with the code above) and errors saying the password needs to be entered.

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |u| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => u.object %>
    <%= u.label :image %>
    <%= u.file_field :image %>

    <%= u.label :desktopinfo, "Desktop Info" %>
    <%= u.text_area :desktopinfo %>
    <%= u.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

This is a pain as I want the info (`:image` and `:desktopinfo`) to change without needing a password to be entered. As you can see I changed the `f.label` to `u.label` on the second form. Does this make any difference?

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks! Dean

**UPDATE**

The current code in the Users controller is:

```
def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        redirect_to @user, :flash => { :success => "Profile updated." }
    else
        @title = "Edit user"
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

Where would I put `@user.update_attributes!(:image => params[:image], :desktopinfo => params[:desktopinfo])`

Also, I am getting `undefined local variable or method`update_user_path'`.

Comment: No I'm using the authentication used in RailsTutorial.org as that's what I've learnt when making the app.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you have some kind of authentication in place. Look for it in your controller or ApplicationController. Depending on which auth package you are using, you can disable it for certain actions. That's apparently what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is because you are associating the form instance with your model, and the model validations are failing when you do not provide the password.

Take a look at the form_for documentation here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

You can use the form_tag here. An example is shown below:

```
<% form_tag(update_user_path, :method=>'post') do %>
 <p>
   Desktop Info:
   <%= text_field_tag "desktopinfo" %>
 </p>
 <p>
   Image:
   <%= file_field_tag "image" %>
 </p>
 <p>
   <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
 </p>
<% end %>
```

And in the controller update action, the form data will be available in `params` hash. Now instead of save you would have to call update_attributes for the fields you want to change:
`@user.update_attributes!(:image => params[:image], :desktopinfo => params[:desktopinfo])`

Take care of validations.

Comment: I think you should spend some time trying to understand what you are doing rather than just getting this working. Spend some time to understand rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: 'update_user_path' was the name of the action, change it accordingly. You probably would want to add a separate action to edit only the 2 fields and not play with the normal update method (assuming you need to edit all fields also somewhere). In the new method replace the update_attributes with the statement I have added. Remove the exclamation! if you are writing it the same way as you have shown.